# What is the unicode for [“] and [”]?

Tags: javascript, unicode

Before POST-ing a form with text fields, I'm able to convert curly quotes from word into normal quotation marks with the following JavaScript snippet:

```
s = s.replace( /\u201c/g, '"' );
s = s.replace( /\u201d/g, '"' );
```

But I've recently encountered double opening/closing quotes as shown in brackets in the Question Title, does anyone know the unicode numbers for these?

Comment: What are you using on the server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks correct for unicode:

for start quote : U+201C

for end quote : U+201D

Source: http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/quotes.html

Comment: Indeed the above code is fine. After refreshing my browser, the above code works. Just one of those refresh browser and it works now situations...

Comment: yeah the cache always gets me!

Answer (score 6):

U+201C and U+201D *are* the Unicode characters `“` and `”`! You should already be catching them.

If you want to also pick up the single-quote characters `‘` and `’` and convert them to `'`, that would be U+2018 and U+2019.

However, this kind of replacement is a Unicode Smell. What are you trying to do here and why? `‚‘’„“”«»–—` etc are perfectly valid characters and if your app can't handle them it won't be able to handle other non-ASCII characters either, which would generally be considered a Bad Thing. If at all possible, it is better to fix whatever problem these characters are currently triggering, rather than sweep it under the rug with a replacement.

Answer (score 3):

You could easily find this out for yourself, in JavaScript, by using `charCodeAt`. You could even do it in the Firebug console:

```
>>> "”".charCodeAt(0).toString(16)
201d
```

To `toString` call at the end even converts it to hexadecimal for you. Remember to pad it with zeros if it's shorted than 4 digits.

Comment: Nice tip, will be using it in the future

Comment: You don’t even need the `0` in this case: `"”".charCodeAt()`

Comment: Note that this technique won’t work for supplementary characters as they consist of surrogate pairs (and this snippet would only get the high surrogate). Use http://mothereff.in/js-escapes.

Answer (score 1):

HTML Escaped entities:

```
&#8220; &#8221;
```

Converted with this tool: http://u-n-i.co/de/